# How do I fix a conversion from type 'ListViewItem' to type 'Integer' is not valid.' error?

Tags: vb.net

I've tried two different codes to get the highest number from a list box, and both of them are giving me an error that says conversion from type ListViewItem to type Integer is not valid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Dim CurrentHighest As Integer = 0
    For Each item As Integer In listpgrades.Items
        If item > CurrentHighest Then CurrentHighest = item
    Next
    txtHSP.Text = CurrentHighest.ToString



    Dim max As Integer = 0
    Dim result = ""
    For Each s As String In listpgrades.Items
        Dim x = CInt(s.Substring((s.LastIndexOf(":") + 2)))
        If max < x Then
            max = x
            result = s
        End If
    Next
    txtHSP.Text = result
```

Comment: Not sure why you keep tagging VBA in your questions. This has nothing to do with VBA. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Are we dealing wih a ListView or a ListBox? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are dealing with a ListView... 
In you first For Each loop item can't be an Integer and a ListViewItem. listpgrades.Items is a collection of ListViewItems.

```
    Dim CurrentHighest As Integer = 0
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If CInt(item.Text) > CurrentHighest Then CurrentHighest = CInt(item.Text)
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = CurrentHighest.ToString
```

If we are talking about a ListBox.

```
    Dim CurrentHighest As Integer = 0
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        If CInt(item) > CurrentHighest Then CurrentHighest = CInt(item)
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = CurrentHighest.ToString
```